# How do I view objects per Foreign Key in one HTML (Django)?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am using Django Framework and creating a notification. I would like to create a notification that can filter by id of the foreign key. But when i tried it, i got all the results,  i am not sure how to filter by id so that per id I can view the flow of the incidents.

**View**

```
def user_reports(request):
profile = get_object_or_404(UserProfile, user=request.user)
incidentReports = IncidentGeneral.objects.all().order_by('-updated_at')
# incident_general = IncidentGeneral.objects.filter(pk=request.id)
notifications = Notification.objects.all().order_by('-date')
paginator = Paginator(incidentReports, 10)
page_number = request.GET.get('page')
page_obj = paginator.get_page(page_number)
if request.method == 'POST':
    for i in incidentReports:
        x = request.POST.get(str(i.id))
        print(x)
        if str(x) == 'on':
            b = IncidentGeneral.objects.get(id=i.id)
            b.soft_delete()
            # b.is_deleted = True
            # b.deleted_at = timezone.now()
            messages.success(request, 'User Report successfully deleted')
context = {
    'profile': profile,
    'incidentReports': page_obj,
    'notifications': notifications,
    # 'IncidentGeneral': IncidentGeneral
}
return render(request, 'pages/user_report.html', context)
```

**Model - Notification**

```
class Notification(models.Model):
TYPES = ((1, 'Reports'), (2, 'User Accounts'), (3, 'Inbox'), (4, 'Attributes Builder'))
incident_report = models.ForeignKey('incidentreport.IncidentGeneral', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
sender = models.ForeignKey('accounts.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True, related_name="noti_from_user")
user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="noti_user")
notification_type = models.IntegerField(choices=TYPES)
remarks = models.CharField(max_length=90, blank=True)
text_preview = models.CharField(max_length=90, blank=True)
date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
is_seen = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

**Model - IncidentGeneral**

```
class IncidentGeneral(SoftDeleteModel):
PENDING = 1
APPROVED = 2
REJECTED = 3
STATUS = (
    (PENDING, 'Pending'),
    (APPROVED, 'Approved'),
    (REJECTED, 'Rejected')
)

IF_DUPLICATE = (
    ('Duplicate', 'Duplicate'),
    ('Possible Duplicate', 'Possible Duplicate'),
    ('Not Duplicate', 'Not Duplicate')
)

WEATHER = (
    ('Clear Night', 'Clear Night'),
    ('Cloudy', 'Cloudy'),
    ('Day', 'Day'),
    ('Fog', 'Fog'),
    ('Hail', 'Hail'),
    ('Partially cloudy day', 'Partially cloudy day'),
    ('Partially cloudy night', 'Partially cloudy night'),
    ('Rain', 'Rain'),
    ('Rain', 'Rain'),
    ('Wind', 'Wind'),
)

LIGHT = (
    ('Dawn', 'Dawn'),
    ('Day', 'Day'),
    ('Dusk', 'Dusk'),
    ('Night', 'Night'),
)

SEVERITY = (
    ('Damage to Property', 'Damage to Property'),
    ('Fatal', 'Fatal'),
    ('Non-Fatal', 'Non-Fatal'),
)

user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, editable=False, null=True, blank=True)
generalid = models.CharField(max_length=250, unique=True, null=True, blank=True)
description = models.TextField(max_length=250, blank=True)
address = models.CharField(max_length=250)
country = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
state = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)
city = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
pin_code = models.CharField(max_length=6, blank=True, null=True)
latitude = models.FloatField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
longitude = models.FloatField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
geo_location = gismodels.PointField(blank=True, null=True, srid=4326) # New field
upload_photovideo = models.FileField(upload_to=incident_image_upload_path, blank=True, null=True)
date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=False, blank=True, null=True)
time = models.TimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=False, blank=True, null=True)
status = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=STATUS, blank=True, null=True)
duplicate =  models.CharField(choices=IF_DUPLICATE,max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)
duplicate_general =  models.ForeignKey('incidentreport.IncidentGeneral', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
accident_factor = models.ForeignKey(AccidentCausation, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
collision_type = models.ForeignKey(CollisionType, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
crash_type = models.ForeignKey(CrashType, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
weather =  models.CharField(choices=WEATHER, max_length=250,blank=True, null=True)
light =  models.CharField(choices=LIGHT,max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)
severity = models.CharField(choices=SEVERITY, max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)
movement_code = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)
created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

def get_status(self):
    if self.status == 1:
        incident_status = 'Pending'
    elif self.status == 2:
        incident_status = 'Approved'
    elif self.status == 3:
        incident_status = 'Rejected'
    return incident_status


def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    # super(IncidentGeneral, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    if self.latitude and self.longitude:
        self.geo_location = Point(float(self.longitude), float(self.latitude))
        super(IncidentGeneral, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

**Snippets of HTML**

```
{% for incident in incidentReports %}
                            {% if incident.user.username %}
                                <tr>
                                   
                                       
                                                {% if incident.status == 2 %}
                                                <td>
                                                    {% comment %} <input type="checkbox" name="{{incident.id}}" id="check" disabled> {% endcomment %}
                                                </td>
                                                {% else %}
                                                <td><input type="checkbox" name="{{incident.id}}" id="check"></td>
                                                {% endif %}
                                                <td>{{incident.user.username}}</td>
                                                <td>{% if incident.user.role %}{{incident.user.get_role}}{% endif %}</td>
                                                <td>{{incident.description}}</td>
                                                <td>{{incident.address}}</td>
                                                {% comment %} <td>{{incident__incident_general.accident_factor}}</td>
                                                <td>{{incident.collision_type}}</td> {% endcomment %}
                                                <td>{{incident.date}}</td>
                                                <td>{{incident.time}}</td>
                                                <td>
                                                    {% if incident.status == 1 %}
                                                    <span class="badge badge-warning">{{incident.get_status}}</span>
                                                    {% elif incident.status == 2 %}
                                                    <span class="badge badge-success">{{incident.get_status}}</span>
                                                    {% elif incident.status == 3 %}
                                                    <span class="badge badge-danger">{{incident.get_status}}</span>
                                                    {% endif %}
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <a href="{% url 'incident_report_general_view' incident.id %}"><i class='bx bxs-folder-open'
                                                        title="View"></i></a>
                           
                                                        {% if incident.status == 2 %} 
                                                        {% else %}     
                                                        <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteModal{{ incident.id }}"><i class='bx bx-trash'
                                                            data-toggle="tooltip" title="Delete" ></i></a>
                                                            {% endif %}
                                                            
                                                            
                                                        
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <a href="#"  data-toggle="collapse"
                                                            data-target="#collapse{{incident.id}}" onclick=""><i class="fa-sharp fa-solid fa-circle-arrow-right"></i></a>
                                                </td>
                                                
                
                                   
                                </tr>
                
                                <tr>
                                    <td id="collapse{{incident.id}}" class="collapse" colspan="10" >
                
                                        <div class="columns is-mobile is-centered">
                                            <div class="column is-half">
                                             
                                          {% for notification in notifications %}
                                          {% if notification.incident_report.id ==  15 %}
                                          {% if notification.remarks == "new incident" %}
                                          
                                          
                                          <div class="notification">
                                            
                                          
                                            <article class="media">
                                          <figure class="media-left">
                                          <p class="image is-64x64">
                                              {% if notification.user.userprofile.profile_picture %}
                                                  <img src="{{ notification.user.userprofile.profile_picture.url }}" alt="Placeholder image">
                                                {% else %}
                                                  <img src="https://bulma.io/images/placeholders/96x96.png" alt="Placeholder image">
                                              {% endif %}
                                          </p>
                                          </figure>
                                          <div class="media-content">
                                          <div class="content">
                                              <strong>{{ notification.user.first_name }} {{ notification.user.last_name }}</strong> <small>&lt;{{ notification.user.username }}&gt;</small> 
                                              <br>
                                              <p>{{ notification.sender.first_name }} {{ notification.sender.last_name }} &lt;{{ notification.sender.username }}&gt; {{ notification.text_preview }}</p>
                                              <strong><small>{{ notification.date|naturaltime }}</small></strong>
                                          </div>
                                          </div>
                                          
                                          <div class="media-right">
                                          <figure class="image is-128x128">
                                            <img src="{{ notification.post.picture.url }}">
                                          </figure>
                                          </div>
                                          </article>
                                          
                                            </div>
                                          
                                            {% endif %}
                                          {% endif %}
                                          
                                          
                                          {% if notification.remarks == "update incident status" %}
                                          
                                          <div class="notification">
                                            
                                          
                                            <article class="media">
                                          <figure class="media-left">
                                          <p class="image is-64x64">
                                              {% if notification.user.userprofile.profile_picture %}
                                                  <img src="{{ notification.user.userprofile.profile_picture.url }}" alt="Placeholder image">
                                                {% else %}
                                                  <img src="https://bulma.io/images/placeholders/96x96.png" alt="Placeholder image">
                                              {% endif %}
                                          </p>
                                          </figure>
                                          <div class="media-content">
                                          <div class="content">
                                              <strong>{{ notification.user.first_name }} {{ notification.user.last_name }}</strong> <small>&lt;{{ notification.user.username }}&gt;</small> 
                                              <br>
                                              <p>{{ notification.user.first_name }} {{ notification.user.last_name }} &lt;{{ notification.user.username }}&gt; <strong> {{ notification.text_preview }} </strong>
                                                with {{ notification.incident_report.address }} from {{ notification.sender.first_name }} {{ notification.sender.last_name }} &lt;{{ notification.sender.username }}&gt; on reported date {{ notification.incident_report.created_at }}
                                              </p>
                                              <strong><small>{{ notification.date|naturaltime }}</small></strong>
                                          </div>
                                          </div>
                                          
                                          <div class="media-right">
                                          <figure class="image is-128x128">
                                            <img src="{{ notification.post.picture.url }}">
                                          </figure>
                                          </div>
                                          </article>
                                          
                                            </div>
                                            {% endif %}
                                          
                                          
                                          {% endfor %}
                                      
                                          </div>
                                          </div>
                                          </div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

in views.py filter:
if your url is like http://url/?id_collapse=id

```
id_collapse = request.GET.get('id_collapse')

incidentReports = IncidentGeneral.objects.get(id=id_collapse).order_by('-updated_at')
notifications = Notification.objects.filter(incident_report__in=incidentReports).order_by('-date')

# your other codes
```

Comment: hi ShiBil, why does it still shows all of the reports? how can I filter only the specific id? Thank you

Comment: HI, What are actually? are you passing Id of report  IncidentGeneral instance? you can filter IncidentGeneral corresponding to user

Comment: hi ShiBil, there is a default id in the HTML "data-target="#collapse{{incident.id}}" can I use this as a filter in the view?

Comment: Are you passing this id as an parameter in url? if so, you will get this id from view.